# "fraction of relevant instances that are retrieved": Should it not be 'those are'?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, pronouns

I was reading a [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) which had this statement:

> recall is the fraction of relevant instances *that* are retrieved

Shouldn't it be the following?

> recall is the fraction of relevant instances ***those*** are retrieved

Comment: No, the base of the construction is "<noun> is the fraction that are retrieved."

Comment: Never sure of the rules for "that are" or "which are" - but one of those is correct

Comment: The answer is 'No' to *those*. However, do let us know why you thought *that* was incorrect and *those* was the right word instead. That will help answer the question. You can also follow our sister site ELL that will be very helpful to you: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=Flyp9GdUZG08GxFV_g6lKw2

Comment: You will find some interesting explanation here: http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/149623-vs-those.html

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no to *those*. The plural of *that* is *those*, that is for sure, but here *that* is used as a relative pronoun, used to identify fraction of relevant instances. There is no use of *those* as a relative pronoun.